# Background video move under NavagationBar with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Trying to fit the video below the NavBar. for both portrait and landscape. Is it possible?

[Background video move to under navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me07w.png)

Here is the following code l'm using

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addNavBarImage()

    let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "homedocapp", withExtension: "mp4")

    Player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL!)

    PlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: Player)
    PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    PlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds

    Player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none


    Player.play()

    view.layer.insertSublayer(PlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemReachEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: Player.currentItem)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why can't you set the `frame` according to your `navigation's` height?:
`PlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.origin.x, y: view.bounds.origin.y + 44, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height - 44)` `//assuming your navigation's height = 44`

Comment: Thank you will try that.

Answer (score 0):

When using storyboard you could set the top space constraint to its superview to 0:
[image]

If you insist on doing it by code, than I suggest you use the cocoa pod: [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) to set the auto layout in the 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' method.

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    player.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top)
}
```

Comment: @o2webdev No problem! You could also just set the player.frame.origin.y to 0, if you want it below the navigation bar. Hope it helps.